# Apache Storm cluster not assigning topology's components to all available workers

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

My topology is configured to use 14 workers and i current have 16 workers available in the cluster.
But when i submit the topology, the "Worker Resources" section on the Storm UI shows that all the 14 workers are up but components (Topology Components) are assigned only to 7. The rest shows N/A (see snapshot below).

[image: snapshot of topology]

The workers/supervisors log files shows no meaningful error(s) as of why some workers are not been assigned components.
I have been googling for the past 6hrs+ to no avail

My environment:

- Apache Storm 2.1.0
- Zookeeper 3.4.9
- One master node (Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS)
- Three supervisor nodes (Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS)

Comment: What does your topology configuration look like? If you don't have enough tasks to spread across the cluster, some workers won't be assigned any components.

Answer (score 0):

What are parallelism hints for each of the components (spouts and bolts) in your topology? If they do not add up to 14 or more then you will not have entries on all worker processes.

Remember you can also set the parallelism of system components such as the Ackers and (in metrics V1) the metrics consumers.